# Symbolic Coordinates not showing

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

So I'm just learning LaTeX so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but i've read the manual, watched youtube videos and read blogs and I still can't figure out why this is not working. I want to do a simple bar graph. Everything goes well in showing the data until I try to add the code that makes it actually look like a bar graph, then, the last coordinate disappears and I do not know why. This is my code, I've linked "pgfplots" at the top (and also "pgf-pie for another graph, if that might be relevant):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    %title= ,
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ybar interval=1,
    xlabel={$estado$},
    ylabel={$frecuencia$},
    symbolic x coords={CA,TX,AZ},
    xtick=data,
    ]

    \addplot coordinates { (CA,9) (TX,8) (AZ,8)};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

The issues start when i add these two lines, which i got from overleaf:

```
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ybar interval=1
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I make a bar graph? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippets compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more complex input data, the *coordinate plot* can quickly become confusing (I would only use the *coordinate plot* for adding individual points or similar). 
Usually you have a table of input data of the kind

```
X         Y
CA        9
TX        8
AZ        8
```

So it's good to know how to do this as a *table plot*.

`symbolic x coords={CA,TX,AZ},` is not needed here, instead: 
`xticklabels from table={\inputdata}{X}, % <--- !`

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % <--- !
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
X         Y
CA        9
TX        8
AZ        8
}\inputdata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0, ymax=10,
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},% not used
ybar,                       % changed
enlarge x limits = 0.4,     %  new
xlabel=\textit{estado},
ylabel=\textit{frecuencia},
%symbolic x coords={CA,TX,AZ}, % not needed
xticklabels from table={\inputdata}{X}, % <--- !
xtick=data, 
]
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex, y=Y]{\inputdata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand much better and it works now! <3

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0, ymax=10,
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ybar,                       % changed
enlarge x limits = 0.4,     %  new
xlabel=\textit{estado},
ylabel=\textit{frecuencia},
symbolic x coords={CA,TX,AZ},
xtick=data,
]
\addplot coordinates { (CA,9) (TX,8) (AZ,8)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped too, what does enlarge x limits do exactly?

Comment: @Kraken, it add space before and after diagram. To see effect, in test remove option  `enlarge x limits`.  What you mean with "helped too". Is suggested solution what you looking for?